# How can use resultReceiver without startService?

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, android-service-binding

I need get some progress of my intent service, but in my search I find the `resultReceiver` and looks good and easy to implement, but the examples what I see pass the receiver throw intent but a can't pass because my intent service its activate by `BroadcastReceiver`. So, I get the progress of `intentService` when the user enter in some activity.

[Here's one example I seen](https://www.journaldev.com/20743/android-intentservice-resultreceiver) and [here another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266178/show-progressbar-or-dialog-from-an-intentservice-for-download-progress)

Answer (score 0):

If you already start your IntentService and don't pass ResultReceiver with this call, there is no way to pass it while IntentService will executed your *onHandleIntent()*. In this case you can make your own Service that will have something like *onHandleIntent(*) that will be executed on HandlerThread (IntentService make the same thing under the hood). So with a simple Service you can receive your ResultReceiver in *onStartCommand()* and make some callback to your UI by checking for instance of ResultReceiver in *onHandleIntent()*